# How to Use Skype for User Login in a website

Tags: .net, authentication, oauth-2.0, skype

We want to use Skype to authenticate users on our ASP.NET Website.

The OAuth protocol allows a user of an application to work with data from a service without providing the app with credentials.As Live,Linkedin,Facebook,etc supports Oauth.
So we were able to authenticate users using Oauth.
But Skype Doesn't support OAuth.How to authenticate Skype users ?

Comment: That sounds a bit like management demands something that seems to be technically impossible?

Comment: @UweKeim Is it not feasible with current Public API's of Skype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skype does not provide OAuth API so it is not possible.

Skype APIs are designed for desktop and embedded integration of their client software, not for the web world. What you want is something which is not the business interest of Microsoft. They have other services for OAuth.

I suggest you tip Microsoft with one billion US dollars or reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Skype now provides OAUTH starting skypekit 4.x